# CSS effect on logo

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am trying to make a logo for header, however I want the last letter to be
inclined.

**like this:**

[image]

and when hovering to be straightened and fall back to it's default position.

**I tried this:**

```css
.nav-branding {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.nav-branding span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  transform-origin: bottom center; /* Set the rotation origin to the bottom center */
  transform: rotate(-25deg);
}

.nav-branding span:hover {
  animation: fallAndBack 1s forwards; /* Play the animation on hover */
}

@keyframes fallAndBack {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: rotate(-25deg); /* Starting and ending position, same as initial rotation */
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(25deg); /* Rotate to the opposite direction at 50% */
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="/" class="nav-branding">BARRETT<span>E</span></a>
```

But it is a little broken and whatever I do it gets worse can someone help.

Thank you in advance! <3

Comment: Rotation is not additive. That is, you don’t rotate something -25deg then straighten it by rotate 25deg.  You rotate it to the upright position (ie no rotation at all) by rotate 0deg.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you mean by broken or getting worst. However, I've tried the following settings and looks pretty close to the image you provided.

```css
.nav-branding {
   display: inline-block;
   text-decoration: none;
   margin: 15px;
   color: blue;
   font-size: 2rem;
   font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.nav-branding span {
   float: right;
   margin: -4px 0rem 0rem 0.2rem;
   padding: 0px 0rem 0px 0rem;
   transform-origin: bottom right;
   transform: rotate(-16deg);
   transition: all ease 300ms; /* Adjust this to make it faster or slower */
}

.nav-branding:hover span {
   transform: rotate(0deg);
   margin: 0px 0rem 0rem -2px;
   padding: 0px 0rem 0px 0rem;
}
```

```html
<a href="/" class="nav-branding">BARRETT<span>E</span></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just removed the `transform-origin` property, margins on the "E" and remove the `transform` in `keyframes`

```css
.nav-branding {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.nav-branding span {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(-25deg);
}

.nav-branding:hover span {
  animation: fallAndBack 1s forwards; /* Play the animation on hover */
}

@keyframes fallAndBack {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: rotate(-25deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="nav-branding">BARRETT<span>E</span></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this instaed of that default animation

```
@keyframes fallAndBack {
  0%{
    transform:rotate(-25deg);
}
  100%{
    transform:rotate(0deg);
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).